# Symfony 2.3 Swiftmailer - 2 e-mails

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I have read a couple of posts here and also documentation of how to include 2 different e-mails in the swiftmailer, but I'm getting an error and don't know why.

Here's my configuration:

```
//config.yml
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: mailer
    mailers:
        mailer:
            transport: smtp
            host:      some.host1
            username:  some.username1
            password:  some.password2
        mailer2:
            transport: gmail
            host:      some.host2
            username:  some.username2
            password:  some.password2
```

I also created a service file:

```
# app/config/services.yml
    services:
        mailer:
            class:        AppBundle\Mailer
            arguments:    [sendmail]
        mailer2:
            class:        AppBundle\Mailer
            arguments:    [sendmail]
```

And in the controller I'm referring to both as:

```
$mailer = $this->get('mailer2');

//or

$mailer = $this->get('mailer');
```

but only the default mailer works. In case of the second mailer I get:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "mailer2".
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to configure a service file.

To get the first mailer:

```
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.mailer');
```

To get the second mailer:

```
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.mailer2');
```

To get the default mailer:

```
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer');
```

See the documentation for [Using Multiple Mailers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#using-multiple-mailers)

Comment: I read the documentation but completely missed the 'swiftmailer. ' part at the beginning, thanks for noticing, looks like it's working now, thanks.